# Minimize frobenius norm of Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

I have an $n\times n $ gram matrix, $G$  (symmetric and positive semidefinite) which captures correlation between set of vectors. The $i,j$ th element of $G$ is given by,
 $\langle a_i, a_j\rangle = \rho_{ij}$ with $\|a_i\|_2 =\|a_j\|_2 =1$. An interesting property of these vectors $a_i$ is that they have a common origin. But this origin can be modified to optimize values in $G$. Further, they have fixed end points. You can imagine this in 2D plane as set of vectors starting at the point  $ (x,y) $ and ending at fixed set of points.

Now, I need to minimize $\|G\|_{F}$, within a given range of $x$, $0<x<X$ for origin of those set of vectors. You can assume $y$ coordinate of origin of the vectors as fixed. I need to identify
$$\arg \min_{x} \|G\|_{F}.$$ If possible can someone please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing $\| G \|_{F}$ is equivalent to minimizing $\| G \|_{F}^{2}$, and 
$G_{i,j}=(a_{i}-x)^{T}(a_{j}-x)$, so your problem can be formulated as

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} G_{i,j}^{2}$

or

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} ((a_{i}-x)^{T}(a_{j}-x))^{2}$

or

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (a_{i}^{T}a_{j}-a_{i}^{T}x-a_{j}^{T}x+x^{T}x)^{2}$

It doesn't appear that this objective will generally be convex.

Comment: If your vectors have a special form and a limited dimension, then that changes the problem considerably.  Why not provide this information in the question...

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I actually tried to identify this optimum point through simulations. For 3 vectors case I see there is a min. value for $||G||_{F}$. BTW vector $$a_i = 1/\sqrt{N}[1\  e^{-j\pi \omega_{i}} \ e^{-2j\pi \omega_{i} } \dots e^{-(N-1)j\pi \omega_{i} }]$$          This vector is spatial signature for a MISO channel. $\omega_{i} = cos(\phi_i)$, where $\phi_i$ is the angle of departure which can take values between $0 - \pi$

Comment: Different spatial signatures corresponds to different users. I am trying here to minimize leakage between different users (by minimizing correlation), and achieve interference alignment. My transmission point is not fixed and I have the flexibility to change the location to that to achieve minimum leakage (This is why I meant origin is common but can be changed to minimize $||G||_{F}$)